# TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.get(...).than is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, axios, react-router

I start recently ReactJS. However I'm not very familiar with ReactJS specially with axios.
In this project I'm getting the data from the API. but it will trigger the given below error.
"TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.get(...).than is not a function"

[image]

```
componentDidMount(){
axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
 .than((response) => {
   this.setState({posts: response.data});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo with promise chaining, it should be `then` instead of `than`, so correct implementation should look like

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ posts: response.data });
      })
  }
```